# Walking Tree - length of tag values

Tags: java, string, tree, sum

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.
I've got a simple HTML page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>World</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goodby</td>
            <td>World</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

What I want to do, is to walk through the entire tree and store the length of each text node. Not only it should contain the length of the current node, but actually ad up to the length of all previous text nodes. Let me clarify what I mean with this example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td> // console output should be string of length: 5
            <td>World</td> // console output should be string of length: 10
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goodby</td> // console output should be string of length: 16
            <td>World</td> // console output should be string of length: 21
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

For that I implemented the following code:

```
private static void print(Node aNode, int aCounter, String aIndent) 
{
    if(aNode.getNodeValue() != null)
        System.out.println(aIndent+aNode.getNodeName() + ", "+aNode.getNodeValue() + ", length: " + aCounter);
    else
        System.out.println(aIndent+aNode.getNodeName());

    Node child = aNode.getFirstChild();

    while (child != null) 
    {
        if(child.getNodeValue() != null)
        {
            aCounter += child.getNodeValue().length();
            print(child, aCounter, aIndent+" ");
        }
        else
            print(child, aCounter, aIndent+" ");

        child = child.getNextSibling();
    }
}
```

I pass the root node to this method. The problem of this code is that it returns only the length of a path. This means I get something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td> // console output is string of length: 5
            <td>World</td> // console output is string of length: 10
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goodby</td> // console output should be string of length: 6 <-- does not consider overall length of previous <tr> content
            <td>World</td> // console output should be string of length: 11
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

So basically I want the length of all characters from the root node to the end of the current tag. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that. Any help would be appreaciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`aCounter` is passed by value (not by reference), so adding a value to it from a recursively called method won't affect the value in the calling method. You probably want to return the new value of `aCounter` to the calling method so that it can update its own version.

Something like this should work:

```
private static void print(Node aNode, int aCounter, String aIndent) 
{
    if(aNode.getNodeValue() != null)
        System.out.println(aIndent+aNode.getNodeName() + ", "+aNode.getNodeValue() + ", length: " + aCounter);
    else
        System.out.println(aIndent+aNode.getNodeName());

    Node child = aNode.getFirstChild();

    while (child != null) 
    {
        if(child.getNodeValue() != null)
        {
            aCounter += child.getNodeValue().length();
        }
        aCounter = print(child, aCounter, aIndent+" ");

        child = child.getNextSibling();
    }

    return aCounter;
}
```

(Although you'll probably want to rethink the names of your variables and methods to make it a bit more readable.)

Comment: Thanks Mattias! That was it. I also followed your advice and chose more meaningful method/variable names.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, [you should accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Just click the check mark at the left of the answer. ;-)